# (Almost homework question) Three gauge-boson amplitude in open string theory

Tags: string-theory

I'm working through  [Polchinski's little book](https://www.kitp.ucsb.edu/sites/default/files/users/joep/JLBS.pdf), in which he describes how to get string amplitudes in a somewhat heuristic manner, without the machinery introduced in the big book. These lectures are wonderful, but problem is that he just states a lot of results without the details. For instance, I'm interested in the three-gauge bosons amplitude (equation 10.12 and equation 6.5.15 in the big book), but I'm getting crazy with an important relative missing -1/2 factor in the cubic term. I attach the calculation, if anybody can help me I would be extremely grateful.

The amplitude is

\begin{align}
    S(k_1,k_2,k_3)&=-\frac{g_o}{\sqrt{8\alpha'^5}}|y_{12}y_{13}y_{23}|\Bigg<\prod_{1,2,3}: \:e_i\cdot\left(\partial_{y_i}X(y_i)\right)e^{ik_i\cdot X(y_i)} :\:\Bigg>.
    \end{align}
 For short let's define the notation

\begin{align}
     &[e_1e^2]\equiv  (e_1\cdot \dot{X}(y_1)) \: e^{ik_2\cdot X(y_2)}=[e^2e_1]=-2i\alpha'\partial_1\ln|y_{12}|e_1\cdot k_2=2i\alpha'\frac{e_1\cdot k_2}{|y_{12}|}\:\:\:(\text{with a $-1$ if } y_1>y_2)\\
        &[e_1e_2]\equiv
        (e_1\cdot \dot{X}(y_1)) \:(e_2\cdot \dot{X}(y_2))  =[e_2e_1]=-2\alpha'e_1\cdot e_2\partial_1\partial_2\ln |y_{12}|=-2\alpha'\frac{e_1\cdot e_2}{ |y_{12}|^2}\\
        &[e^1e^2]\equiv  
        e^{ik_1\cdot X(y_1)} \: e^{ik_2\cdot X(y_2)}=[e^2e^1]=|y_{12}|^{2\alpha'k_1\cdot k_2},
 \end{align}

where the products are understood to be contracted, and up to momentum-conserving Delta functions. The $[e^i e^j]$ will all be one because of the massless condition. Thus
 \begin{align}
   S(k_1,k_2,k_3)=-\frac{g_o}{\sqrt{8\alpha'^5}}|y_{12}y_{13}y_{23}|&\Bigg([e_1e^2][e_2e^3][e_3e^1]+[e_1e^3][e_3e^2][e_2e^1]\nonumber\\
   &+[e_1e_2]\left(\:[e^1e^3][e_3e^2]+[e^1e_3][e^3e^2]\:\right)+(1,3)+(2,3)\Bigg),
 \end{align}

with the repetitions $(1,3)$ and $(2,3)$ applying only to the second term. So we have,

\begin{align}
   S(k_1,k_2,k_3)=-\frac{g_o}{\sqrt{8\alpha'^5}}|y_{12}y_{13}y_{23}|&\Bigg((2i\alpha')^3\frac{e_1\cdot k_2}{|y_{12}|}\frac{e_2\cdot k_3}{|y_{23}|}\frac{-e_3\cdot k_1}{|y_{13}|}+(2i\alpha')^3\frac{e_1\cdot k_3}{|y_{13}|}\frac{-e_3\cdot k_2}{|y_{23}|}\frac{-e_2\cdot k_1}{|y_{21}|}\nonumber\\
   &-2\alpha'\frac{e_1\cdot e_2}{ |y_{12}|^2}\left(\:2i\alpha'\frac{-e_3\cdot k_2}{|y_{23}|}+2i\alpha'\frac{-e_3\cdot k_1}{|y_{13}|}\:\right)+(1,3)+(2,3)\Bigg)\\
   =-\frac{g_o}{\sqrt{8\alpha'^5}}|y_{12}y_{13}y_{23}|&\Bigg(\frac{8i\alpha'^3}{|y_{12}y_{13}y_{23}|}\left(e_1\cdot k_2\:e_2\cdot k_3\:e_3\cdot k_1-e_1\cdot k_3\:e_3\cdot k_2\:e_2\cdot k_1\right)\nonumber\\
   &+4i\alpha'^2\frac{e_1\cdot e_2}{ |y_{12}|^2}\:e_3\cdot\left(\:\frac{ k_2}{|y_{23}|}+\frac{ k_1}{|y_{13}|}\:\right)+(1,3)+(2,3)\Bigg).
 \end{align}

The dot products in the first factor sum up to

\begin{equation}
    e_1\cdot k_2\:e_2\cdot k_3\:e_3\cdot k_1-e_1\cdot k_3\:e_3\cdot k_2\:e_2\cdot k_1= \frac{1}{4}e_1\cdot(k_2-k_3)\:e_2\cdot(k_3-k_1)\:e_3\cdot(k_1-k_2),
 \end{equation}

and also, for $y_1=0, y_2=1, y_3=\infty$,

\begin{align}
     e_3\cdot\left(|y_{13}|k_2+|y_{23}|k_1 \right)=  e_3\cdot\left(y_3(k_2+k_1)-y_1k_2-y_2k_1\right)=-e_3\cdot k_1=-\frac{1}{2}e_3\cdot(k_1-k_2),
 \end{align}

therefore,

\begin{align}
   S(k_1,k_2,k_3)
   =-\frac{ig_o\alpha'^2}{\sqrt{8\alpha'^5}}&\Bigg(2\alpha'e_1\cdot(k_2-k_3)\:e_2\cdot(k_3-k_1)\:e_3\cdot(k_1-k_2)\nonumber\\
   &-2(e_1\cdot e_2)\:e_3\cdot(k_1-k_2)+(1,3)+(2,3)\Bigg)\\
   =\frac{2ig_o\alpha'^2}{\sqrt{8\alpha'^5}}&\Bigg(-\alpha'e_1\cdot(k_2-k_3)\:e_2\cdot(k_3-k_1)\:e_3\cdot(k_1-k_2)\nonumber\\
   &+(e_1\cdot e_2)\:e_3\cdot(k_1-k_2)+(1,3)+(2,3)\Bigg)\\
     =\frac{ig_o}{\sqrt{2\alpha'}}&\Bigg(-\alpha'e_1\cdot(k_2-k_3)\:e_2\cdot(k_3-k_1)\:e_3\cdot(k_1-k_2)\nonumber\\
   &+(e_1\cdot e_2)\:e_3\cdot(k_1-k_2)+(1,3)+(2,3)\Bigg)
 \end{align}

Apparently, I missed a factor of -1/2 in the first term, the prefactor should be $\alpha'/2$. Also Green-Schwarz-Witten report the same amplitude as Polchinski, but nowhere in the literature I have seen the detailed calculation. The prefactor is relevant for the efective gauge action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not gone through your calculation, but this is my detailed calculation.

We first consider the matter part:
\begin{align}
S_3^{X \mu\nu\sigma} \left\langle  :  \dot{X}^\mu e^{ik_1\cdot X}(y_1)  : \,  :  \dot{X}^\nu e^{ik_2\cdot X}(y_2)  : \,  :  \dot{X}^\sigma e^{ik_3\cdot X}(y_3)  : \, \right \rangle
\end{align}
From (6.2.36) we get 
\begin{align}
S_3^{X\mu\nu\sigma}  =&  i C_{D_2}^X (2\pi)^{26} \delta^{26}(\sum_i k_i) |y_{12}|^{2\alpha' k_1\cdot k_2}|y_{13}|^{2\alpha' k_1\cdot k_3}|y_{23}|^{2\alpha' k_2\cdot k_3} \Big[ v^\mu (y_1) v^\nu (y_2) v^\sigma (y_3) \nonumber\\
&+ v^\mu (y_1) \langle q^\nu(y_2) q^\sigma (y_3) \rangle + v^\nu (y_2) \langle q^\mu(y_1) q^\sigma (y_3) \rangle + v^\sigma (y_3) \langle q^\mu(y_1) q^\nu (y_2) \rangle  \Big] \nonumber\\
& \times \mathrm{tr} {\lambda^{a_1}  \lambda^{a_2} \lambda^{a_3}} + (k_2,a_2,\epsilon_2) \leftrightarrow (k_3,a_3,\epsilon_3) \nonumber\\
 =&  i C_{D_2}^X (2\pi)^{26} \delta^{26}(\sum_i k_i) |y_{12}|^{2\alpha' k_1\cdot k_2}|y_{13}|^{2\alpha' k_1\cdot k_3}|y_{23}|^{2\alpha' k_2\cdot k_3}  \nonumber\\
&\times \Bigg\{(-2i\alpha')^3  \left( \frac{k_2^\mu}{y_{12}} + \frac{k_3^\mu}{y_{13}} \right) \left( \frac{k_1^\nu}{y_{21}} + \frac{k_3^\nu}{y_{23}} \right)\left( \frac{k_1^\sigma}{y_{31}} + \frac{k_2^\sigma}{y_{32}} \right) \nonumber\\
& + (-2\alpha')(-2i\alpha') \left[   
   \left( \frac{k_2^\mu}{y_{12}} + \frac{k_3^\mu}{y_{13}} \right) \frac{\eta^{\nu\sigma}}{y_{23}^2}  
+ \left( \frac{k_1^\nu}{y_{21}} + \frac{k_3^\nu}{y_{23}} \right) \frac{\eta^{\mu\nu}}{y_{13}^2} 
+\left( \frac{k_1^\sigma}{y_{31}} + \frac{k_2^\sigma}{y_{32}} \right) \frac{\eta^{\mu\sigma}}{y_{12}^2} 
\right]\Bigg\}\nonumber\\
& \times \mathrm{tr} {\lambda^{a_1}  \lambda^{a_2} \lambda^{a_3}} + (k_2,a_2,\epsilon_2) \leftrightarrow (k_3,a_3,\epsilon_3) 
\end{align}
The first thing we note is that because of momentum conservation and mass-shell condition
\begin{align}
0= k_1^2 =(-k_2-k_3)^2 = k_2^2+k_3^2 + 2 k_1\cdot k_2 \Rightarrow k_1\cdot k_2 =0
\end{align}
We now add the ghost contribution $\langle ccc\rangle = C_{D_2}^g y_{12} y_{13} y_{23}$, the polarisation vectors, the cosmological term $e^{-\lambda}$  and the normalisation of the boson vertex operators, $-ig_0/\sqrt{2\alpha'}$ see (3.6.26), and we find
\begin{align}
S_{D_2}^{ggg} =& S_{D_2} (k_1,a_1, \epsilon_1; k_2,a_2, \epsilon_2; k_3,a_3, \epsilon_3) \nonumber\\
=& \left(-\frac{ig_0}{\sqrt{2\alpha'}}\right)^3
4i\alpha'^2 C_{D_2}^X C_{D_2}^g e^{-\lambda} \epsilon_{1\mu}  \epsilon_{2\nu}  \epsilon_{3\sigma}  (2\pi)^{26} \delta^{26}(\sum_i k_i)  y_{12} y_{13} y_{23}\nonumber\\
&\times  \Bigg[ 2\alpha'  \left( \frac{k_2^\mu}{y_{12}} + \frac{k_3^\mu}{y_{13}} \right) \left( \frac{k_1^\nu}{y_{21}} + \frac{k_3^\nu}{y_{23}} \right)\left( \frac{k_1^\sigma}{y_{31}} + \frac{k_2^\sigma}{y_{32}} \right) \nonumber\\
&+ \left( \frac{k_2^\mu}{y_{12}} + \frac{k_3^\mu}{y_{13}} \right) \frac{\eta^{\nu\sigma}}{y_{23}^2}  
+ \left( \frac{k_1^\nu}{y_{21}} + \frac{k_3^\nu}{y_{23}} \right) \frac{\eta^{\mu\nu}}{y_{13}^2} 
+\left( \frac{k_1^\sigma}{y_{31}} + \frac{k_2^\sigma}{y_{32}} \right) \frac{\eta^{\mu\sigma}}{y_{12}^2} 
\Bigg]\nonumber\\
& \times \mathrm{tr} {\lambda^{a_1}  \lambda^{a_2} \lambda^{a_3}} + (k_2,a_2,\epsilon_2) \leftrightarrow (k_3,a_3,\epsilon_3) 
\end{align}
Let us first simplify the pre-factor. Use (6.4.14), i.e. $C_{D_2}^X C_{D_2}^g e^{-\lambda} = C_{D_2} = 1/\alpha' g_0^2$ to write
\begin{align}
\left(-\frac{ig_0}{\sqrt{2\alpha'}}\right)^3
4i\alpha'^2 C_{D_2}^X C_{D_2}^g e^{-\lambda}  = -\frac{2 \alpha' g_0^3}{\sqrt{2\alpha'}} C_{D_2}^X C_{D_2}^g e^{-\lambda} = -\frac{2g_0}{\sqrt{2\alpha'}} =-2 g_0' 
\end{align}
in the last line we have used (6.5.14), i.e. $g_0'= g_0/\sqrt{2\alpha'}$.
The three boson amplitude thus becomes
\begin{align}
S_{D_2}^{ggg} =& S_{D_2} (k_1,a_1, \epsilon_1; k_2,a_2, \epsilon_2; k_3,a_3, \epsilon_3) \nonumber\\
=& -2g_0' \epsilon_{1\mu}  \epsilon_{2\nu}  \epsilon_{3\sigma} (2\pi)^{26} \delta^{26}(\sum_i k_i)  y_{12} y_{13} y_{23}   \Bigg[ 2\alpha'  \left( \frac{k_2^\mu}{y_{12}} + \frac{k_3^\mu}{y_{13}} \right) \left( \frac{k_1^\nu}{y_{21}} + \frac{k_3^\nu}{y_{23}} \right)\left( \frac{k_1^\sigma}{y_{31}} + \frac{k_2^\sigma}{y_{32}} \right) \nonumber\\
&+ \left( \frac{k_2^\mu}{y_{12}} + \frac{k_3^\mu}{y_{13}} \right) \frac{\eta^{\nu\sigma}}{y_{23}^2}  
+ \left( \frac{k_1^\nu}{y_{21}} + \frac{k_3^\nu}{y_{23}} \right) \frac{\eta^{\mu\nu}}{y_{13}^2} 
+\left( \frac{k_1^\sigma}{y_{31}} + \frac{k_2^\sigma}{y_{32}} \right) \frac{\eta^{\mu\sigma}}{y_{12}^2} 
\Bigg]\nonumber\\
& \times \mathrm{tr} {\lambda^{a_1}  \lambda^{a_2} \lambda^{a_3}} + (k_2,a_2,\epsilon_2) \leftrightarrow (k_3,a_3,\epsilon_3) 
\end{align}
In the remainder of the calculation we will repeatedly use the fact that $k_i\cdot \epsilon_i=0$ for $i=1,2,3$. This actually means that we can simply ignore any terms that have a $k_1^\mu, k_2^\nu$ or a $k_3^\sigma$ as these will be contracted with the polarisation vectors $\epsilon_{1\mu},\epsilon_{2\nu}$ and $\epsilon_{3\sigma}$ respectively. 
Consider first the terms linear in momentum and take the first such terms
\begin{align}
& y_{12} y_{13} y_{23} \left( \frac{k_2^\mu}{y_{12}} + \frac{k_3^\mu}{y_{13}} \right) \frac{\eta^{\nu\sigma}}{y_{23}^2}  =
 \frac{\eta^{\nu\sigma}}{y_{23}}(k_2^\mu y_{13} +k_3^\mu y_{12}) \nonumber\\
=& \frac{\eta^{\nu\sigma}}{2y_{23}}\big[k_2^\mu y_{13} +(-k_1^\mu-k_3^\mu ) y_{13}+k_3^\mu y_{12}+(-k_1^\mu-k_2^\mu) y_{12}\big] \nonumber\\
=&  \frac{\eta^{\nu\sigma}}{2y_{23}} (k_{23}^\mu y_{13} +k_{32}^\mu y_{12} ) =  \frac{k_{23}^\mu \eta^{\nu\sigma}}{2y_{23}} (y_{13}-y_{12})=
 \frac{k_{23}^\mu \eta^{\nu\sigma}}{2y_{23}} y_{23} = \frac{1}{2} k_{23}^\mu \eta^{\nu\sigma}
\end{align}
Contracting with the polarisation vectors $\epsilon_1^\mu \epsilon_2^\nu \epsilon_3^\sigma$ this gives a contribution $\frac{1}{2} (\epsilon_1\cdot k_{23} )(
\epsilon_2\cdot \epsilon_3)$. The two other terms linear in the momenta give similar contributions so that we can write 
\begin{align}
S_{D_2}^{ggg [1]} 
=&  -g_0' (2\pi)^{26} \delta^{26}(\sum_i k_i) \times \big[ 
(\epsilon_1\cdot k_{23} )(\epsilon_2\cdot \epsilon_3) + (\epsilon_2\cdot k_{31} )(\epsilon_3\cdot \epsilon_1)+ (\epsilon_3\cdot k_{12} )(\epsilon_1\cdot \epsilon_2) \big]\nonumber\\
&\qquad \times \mathrm{tr} {\lambda^{a_1}  \lambda^{a_2} \lambda^{a_3}} + (k_2,a_2,\epsilon_2) \leftrightarrow (k_3,a_3,\epsilon_3)  \nonumber\\
&= -g_0' (2\pi)^{26} \delta^{26}(\sum_i k_i) \Bigg\{ \big[ 
(\epsilon_1\cdot k_{23} )(\epsilon_2\cdot \epsilon_3) + (\epsilon_2\cdot k_{31} )(\epsilon_3\cdot \epsilon_1) \nonumber\\
&  + (\epsilon_3\cdot k_{12} )(\epsilon_1\cdot \epsilon_2) \big] \mathrm{tr} {\lambda^{a_1}  \lambda^{a_2} \lambda^{a_3}}  \nonumber\\
&+
\big[ 
(\epsilon_1\cdot k_{32} )(\epsilon_3\cdot \epsilon_2) + (\epsilon_3\cdot k_{21} )(\epsilon_2\cdot \epsilon_1)+ (\epsilon_2\cdot k_{13} )(\epsilon_1\cdot \epsilon_3) \big] \mathrm{tr} {\lambda^{a_1}  \lambda^{a_3} \lambda^{a_2}}
 \Bigg\}
 \end{align}
 and finally for the linear term
 \begin{align}
 S_{D_2}^{ggg [1]}&= -g_0' (2\pi)^{26} \delta^{26}(\sum_i k_i) \nonumber\\
&\times \big[ 
(\epsilon_1\cdot k_{23} )(\epsilon_2\cdot \epsilon_3) + (\epsilon_2\cdot k_{31} )(\epsilon_3\cdot \epsilon_1)+ (\epsilon_3\cdot k_{12} )(\epsilon_1\cdot \epsilon_2) \big] \mathrm{tr} {\lambda^{a_1} [ \lambda^{a_2}, \lambda^{a_3}}]
\end{align}
Let us now focus on the term cubic in the momenta. We have
\begin{align}
&\left( \frac{k_2^\mu}{y_{12}} + \frac{k_3^\mu}{y_{13}} \right) \left( \frac{k_1^\nu}{y_{21}} + \frac{k_3^\nu}{y_{23}} \right)\left( \frac{k_1^\sigma}{y_{31}} + \frac{k_2^\sigma}{y_{32}} \right) \nonumber\\
=& \frac{k_2^\mu y_{13} +k_3^\mu y_{12}}{y_{12} y_{13}} \frac{k_1^\nu y_{23} +k_3^\nu y_{21}}{y_{21} y_{23}} \frac{k_1^\sigma y_{32} +k_2^\sigma y_{31}}{y_{31} y_{32}} \nonumber\\
=& \frac{[k_2^\mu y_{13} +(-k_1^\mu-k_2^\mu) y_{12}] [ k_1^\nu y_{23} +(-k_1^\nu-k_2^\nu) y_{21}][ k_1^\sigma y_{32} +(-k_1^\sigma -k_3^\sigma) y_{31} ]}{y_{12} y_{13} y_{21}y_{23} y_{31} y_{32}}\nonumber\\
=&- \frac{k_2^\mu(y_{13}-y_{12}) k_1^\nu(y_{23} -y_{21}) ( k_1^\sigma (y_{32} - y_{31})} {y_{12}^2 y_{13}^2 y_{23}^2}\nonumber\\
 =& \frac{k_2^\mu k_1^\nu k_1^\sigma y_{23} y_{13} y_{12}}{ y_{12}^2 y_{13}^2 y_{23}^2}
= \frac{k_2^\mu k_1^\nu k_1^\sigma }{ y_{12} y_{13} y_{23}}
\end{align}
We have repeatedly used momentum conservation and the fact that $\epsilon_1\cdot k_1 = \epsilon_2\cdot k_2 =\epsilon_3\cdot k_3 =0$. 
We now rewrite
\begin{align}
&k_2^\mu k_1^\nu k_1^\sigma  = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3  [k_2^\mu + (-k_1^\mu-k_3^\mu) ] [k_1^\nu + (-k_2^\nu-k_3^\nu) ]
 [k_1^\sigma + (-k_2^\sigma-k_3^\sigma) ]\nonumber\\
 & = \frac{1}{8} k_{23}^\mu k_{13}^\nu k_{12}^\sigma
 \end{align}
 Bringing it all together, we find for the cubic terms
 \begin{align}
S_{D_2}^{ggg [3]}= & -2g_0' (2\pi)^{26} \delta^{26}(\sum_i k_i)  y_{12} y_{13} y_{23}  \epsilon_1^\mu \epsilon_2^\nu \epsilon_3^\sigma 2 \alpha'  \frac{k_{23}^\mu k_{13}^\nu k_{12}^\sigma}{8y_{12} y_{13} y_{23} }  \mathrm{tr} {\lambda^{a_1}  \lambda^{a_2} \lambda^{a_3}}   \nonumber\\
&   + (k_2,a_2,\epsilon_2) \leftrightarrow (k_3,a_3,\epsilon_3) 
   \nonumber\\
  =& -g_0' (2\pi)^{26} \delta^{26}(\sum_i k_i)\frac{\alpha'}{2} (\epsilon_1\cdot k_{23})(\epsilon_2\cdot k_{13})(\epsilon_3\cdot k_{12}) \mathrm{tr} {\lambda^{a_1}  \lambda^{a_2} \lambda^{a_3}}     \nonumber\\
&    + (k_2,a_2,\epsilon_2) \leftrightarrow (k_3,a_3,\epsilon_3) \nonumber\\
 =& -g_0' (2\pi)^{26} \delta^{26}(\sum_i k_i)\frac{\alpha'}{2} \Big[ (\epsilon_1\cdot k_{23})(\epsilon_2\cdot k_{13})(\epsilon_3\cdot k_{12}) \mathrm{tr} {\lambda^{a_1}  \lambda^{a_2} \lambda^{a_3}}   \nonumber\\
 &  +  (\epsilon_1\cdot k_{32})(\epsilon_3\cdot k_{12})(\epsilon_2\cdot k_{13}) \mathrm{tr} {\lambda^{a_1}  \lambda^{a_3} \lambda^{a_2}}  \Big]
 \nonumber\\
  =& -g_0' (2\pi)^{26} \delta^{26}(\sum_i k_i)\frac{\alpha'}{2}  (\epsilon_1\cdot k_{23})(\epsilon_2\cdot k_{13})(\epsilon_3\cdot k_{12}) \mathrm{tr} {\lambda^{a_1}[ \lambda^{a_2}, \lambda^{a_3}}  ]
 \end{align}
 Bringing the cubic and the linear terms together we thus find
\begin{align} 
 S_{D_2} (k_1,a_1, \epsilon_1&; k_2,a_2, \epsilon_2; k_3,a_3, \epsilon_3) = -g_0' (2\pi)^{26} \delta^{26}(\sum_i k_i)  \nonumber\\
 & \times 
 \Big[ 
(\epsilon_1\cdot k_{23} )(\epsilon_2\cdot \epsilon_3) + (\epsilon_2\cdot k_{31} )(\epsilon_3\cdot \epsilon_1)+ (\epsilon_3\cdot k_{12} )(\epsilon_1\cdot \epsilon_2) \nonumber\\
& \quad + \frac{\alpha'}{2}  (\epsilon_1\cdot k_{23})(\epsilon_2\cdot k_{13})(\epsilon_3\cdot k_{12})\Big] \mathrm{tr} {\lambda^{a_1}[ \lambda^{a_2}, \lambda^{a_3}}  ]
\end{align}
which is (6.5.15), up to a factor $-i$, but this might just be a normalisation issue of the boson vertex operator as $-i = i^3$.

Comment: I found it very useful, thank you. Though it's not in the spirit of Joe's little book (where he doesn't introduce ghosts at all) it helped me very much.

Comment: thanks. if you go to my profile, you can find a link to more notes on Joe's (big) book.